# Anonymous Function Causing Problems

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

The only thing that is giving me problems is executing an anonymous function call. I even made an empty call to see if there was problems with the code inside; that isn't the case.

This is the format I write them in:

```
(function(){})();
```

I'm positive that that is correct and standard use, but it keeps throwing *this* **error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is
>   not a function(anonymous function)

The error can be found [HERE](https://preview.c9.io/lemony_andrew/arcadegames/pongindex.html?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io) while the site is running.

*the code excerpt above is no different than what's in my program*

Comment: Does the specific code posted (empty arguments, empty body) give you an error? If not, what's the simplest code that does give you the error? If it does produce the error, what context are you calling it in, and what Javascript engine is complaining about it? Does a script whose only content is that line give you the error?

Comment: The posted code produces no error in Chrome 43. Just tried it.

Comment: @user2357112 The exact code posted(the empty anonymous function) throws the error. I am using vanilla js with no added libraries and there's only 120 lines of code. I'm calling it in the global scope.

Comment: What happens if you remove the other 119 lines? Have you checked that the previous line has a semicolon?

Comment: Your exact code - [no problem](http://jsfiddle.net/1a0g0ouf/1/).

Comment: @user2357112 it appears to be a syntax error like you suggested. You should post this as your answer. I don't put semi-colons at the end of my function declarations because I always seem to think that's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: And now you've learned, semi-colons aren't always optional in JS even if the parser tries to insert them where needed, sometimes it fails.

Comment: Tried in **iojs** 1.81 and this doesn't produce any error either.

Comment: @adeneo I don't leave out semi-colons, I actively use them. I just don't use them at the end of function and object declarations because I've always thought that was wrong. I'll just have to start using them there too.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew Function declarations don't have this problem. Function expressions do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code giving you trouble is

```
    ctrl.deleteObject = function(obj){
        var index = ctrl.objects.indexOf(obj);
        if( index > -1 ){
            this.objects.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    //}


    // //START GAME
     (function(){
     //ctrl.createObject(new PlayerPaddle(50, 50));
        //ctrl.init();
    })();
```

Stripping out comments, we get

```
    ctrl.deleteObject = function(obj){
        var index = ctrl.objects.indexOf(obj);
        if( index > -1 ){
            this.objects.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
     (function(){
    })();
```

The assignment to `ctrl.deleteObject` is not terminated by a semicolon, and the parentheses on the next line look like a valid continuation of the assignment, so Javascript doesn't insert a semicolon for you. Instead of an assignment and an anonymous function call, you end up calling the function you were trying to assign to `ctrl.deleteObject`, and then calling its return value, which isn't a function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have something like

```js
(function() { return 123; })
(function(){})();
```

It becomes

```js
(123)();
```

But `123` is not a function. So it throws

> TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

To fix it, add a semi-colon:

```
(function() { return 123; }); // <-- semi-colon
(function(){})(); // No error
```

Note the semi-colon is needed in function expressions, but not necessary in function declarations:

```js
function foo() {} // No semi-colon
(function(){})(); // No error
```